# GREP for next word follow a string containing a variable

Tags: regex, parsing, sed, grep

I have this string in a bash variable

```
name : br-ext protocols : [protocol] name : br-ex protocols : [] name : br-local protocols : [other protocol] name : br-int protocols : []
```

and a variable $br containing on of the name : values (i.e br-ext)

Given $br, I want to access the protocol string that follows it (so $br br-ext should get 'protocol' and $br-ex should get '')

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to access the value of the variable

```
echo $protocols | grep -oP "(?<=\"$br\")[^ ]*"
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```sh
echo "$protocols" | grep -oP "$br\\s+protocols\\s*:\\s*\\[\\K[^][]*"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/ITgssx)

Note that `$protocols` is inside double quotes (the variable is quoted).

The pattern matches

- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `protocols` - the word `protocols`
- `\s*:\s*` - a colon enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `\[` - a `[` char
- `\K` - remove all text matched so far
- `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't seem to work as it does in your demo? I recall reading that perhaps some regex syntax isnt available on all systems?

Comment: @sdaniele See [how it works](https://regex101.com/r/TqD9Vs/1). `-P` enables the PCRE regex syntax, the same is selected on the regex testing site. See [the screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/1tPYRAi) proving it works in Ubuntu Linux.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code, where `protocol` and `br` are shell variables.

```
echo "$protocols" | 
awk -v br="$br" '
{
  match($0,br" [^:]*:[[:space:]]+[^]]*")
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/.*\[/,"",val)
  print val
}
'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
echo "$protocols" |               ##Printing value of protocols variable and sending it as standard input to awk program here.
awk -v br="$br" '                 ##Starting awk program from here, defining br variable of awk which has br shell variable value in it.
{
  match($0,br" [^:]*:[[:space:]]+[^]]*") ##using match function of awk to match br value followed by space till colon 1st occurrence followed by spaces till 1st occurrence of ].
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)   ##Creating val which has matched regex sub string value here.
  sub(/.*\[/,"",val)              ##Using sub to substitute everything till [ in val.
  print val                       ##printing val here.
}
'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `br` can never contain regexp metachars or `/`s then using any sed in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ str='name : br-ext protocols : [protocol] name : br-ex protocols : [] name : br-local protocols : [other protocol] name : br-int protocols : []'

$ br='br-ext'
$ echo "$str" | sed -n 's/.*name : '"$br"' protocols : \[\([^]]*\).*/\1/p'
protocol

$ br='br-ex'
$ echo "$str" | sed -n 's/.*name : '"$br"' protocols : \[\([^]]*\).*/\1/p'

$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in pure Bash, without using external utilities. (But the solution is definitely bash-specific. Other similar features exist in other shells, but there's not standardization.)

```sh
[[ $protocol =~ "name : $br protocols : ["([^]]*)"]" ]] \
  && extracted=${BASH_REMATCH[1]} \
  || echo "Not found"
```

The above pattern assumes the input is exactly as shown in your question. Some adjustment might be necessary if that assumption is wrong.

- `=~` is the regex match operator used in Bash's extended conditional expression (`[[...]]`) syntax
- `$BASH_REMATCH` is where `=~` leaves the captured strings if the pattern has captures.
- As in most regex implementations, `[^]]` means "anything other than `]` because the first character in a character set is allowed to be `]` or `-`.
- **Note:** regex metacharacters in regular expressions can be tricky because the part of the regular expression in quotes is treated as an ordinary string, regardless of its comments. So I couldn't just write the whole pattern in quotes.